# Gazebo System Requirements

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I intend to buy a new laptop and configure a PC and wish to run Gazebo under Ubuntu. My experiments background are **quadrotors swarm** (**more than 15 vehicles**) whose software is based on PX4 SITL with Gazebo6.6.

I searched the internet and found the similar answers,

- http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8919/gazebo-system-requirements/
- http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4191/can-a-graphics-card-speed-up-gazebo/.

But these answers were little outmoded and I would like to know that

- Whether NVIDIA GeForce is the bottleneck for Gazebo performance (real-time factor)?
- On your experience related to Gazebo-based UAV Swarm Simulation, which type processor and graphic card are recommended?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15125/gazebo-system-requirements/) by [Weiwei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2623/weiwei/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lyndwyrm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2869/lyndwyrm/) on 2017-01-02**:
I'm running gazebo on an octa-core, 8GB Ram and an nvidia quadro 5000, and it's already kind of laggy for my single robot simulation :D. The simulation takes up roughly 3 cores(running i3 instead of KDE).
So I would think my graphics card makes it slow.

**Comment by [Weiwei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2623/weiwei/) on 2017-01-03**:
@Lyndwyrm Thank you for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are multiple bottlenecks in simulation, which depend on your use case. For example:

1. If you have lots of camera sensors, or a few high-resolution cameras, then rendering can be a bottleneck.
2. If you have a robot with many degrees of freedom, then physics (CPU) will be a bottleneck.
3. It is also likely that you have a combination of 1 & 2.

We recommend, and develop Gazebo on, a fairly modern computer (within the last two years). Not bleeding edge, but not 5 years old either.

Keep in mind that throwing more expensive hardware at a problem is not usually the best solution. Chances are you should modify simulation parameters to achieve desired results.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Weiwei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2623/weiwei/) on 2017-01-04**:
@nkoenig Thank you for your kind reply. Would the Nvidia Graphic Card will speed up the rendering or ODE calculation? or all the ODE burden is for CPUs?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2017-01-04**:
Currently ODE uses only the CPU.

**Comment by [Weiwei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2623/weiwei/) on 2017-01-04**:
@nkoenig Great. So Nvidia Graphic Card only enhances the rendering assignments?